# Spring authentication, avoid unnecessary BCrypt operation

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, denial-of-service

Today I was looking for a way to make our servers more robust against a very special way of DOS attack.

We use BCrypt with a strength of 12 to store user passwords.
Validation of a password on our environments may take up to 500ms.

It's acceptable for a user on login.
I think somebody may flood our servers with login request with invalid passwords to take it under heavy load.

First I thought this problem can only occur with an existing user but then during debugging I found this code in the DaoAuthenticationProvider:

```
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
        if(authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userNotFoundEncodedPassword, presentedPassword, null);
        }
        throw notFound;
```

In case of a UsernameNotFoundException it checks the provided password against a userNotFoundEncodedPassword!
Also here the system needs the same calculation time, cause the userNotFoundEncodedPassword also has a strength of 12.
Where is it set?
How can I avoid that calculation?
Do I have to write my own AuthenticationProvider?

Comment: Understand the purpose of that calculation: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2056

Comment: Understand that, but how then protect the Server from heavy load by massiv authentication requests?

Comment: rate limiting...ip blocking...intrusian detection...captcha during high volumes.  standard DDOS countermeasures.  If your app is important enough to be DDOS'd then you need to use proper DDOS techniques.

Comment: I don't think it's a question of importance. So all of this sounds like additional software? I thought to just solve it with my Java application. Filters or interceptors that handle it...